# Honorifics used by students the same age

Tags: word-choice, usage, mandarin, vocabulary

Can anyone tell me honorifics that would be used by high school aged students who are the same age? More specifically, is there any honorific that would be used by a student being extremely polite to another student (again, the same age).

I know it's common to use surname and given name or just given name, but I wanted to know if there is a word for when someone is being especially polite.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> honorifics that would be used by high school-aged students who are **the same age**

If the same-aged person has a title, you can use it as an honorific

For example:

If 陳同學 is the 學生會長 of your school, you can call him "陳會長"

If 張同學 is your sports team's captain, you can call him "張隊長"

先生 (Mr.) is the universal honorific for an adult male of all ages, 陳先生 can be your age or ten years older

女仕 (Ms.) is the universal honorific for an adult female of all ages, 張女仕 can be your age or ten years older

小姐 (Miss) is the universal honorific for a single adult female

To show respect, politeness, or fondness, same-aged people would add 兄 before the last name or first name of a similar-aged friend

For example:

陳志豪 --> 陳兄 or 志豪兄

張國強 --> 張兄 or 國強兄

If you know for sure that you are younger, you would use 陳兄 or 陳老兄

If you know for sure that you are older, you would use 張兄弟 or 張老弟 instead

A polite address between same-aged people is not considered honorific.

Generally, high school students would address their fellow students by their full names only, using honorific or polite addresses is considered unusual and too formal

Using nicknames might be the most common way to address same-aged high school friends

Answer (score 0):

A school kid shows respect to the same age pal by treating them as a brotherly/sisterly figure - 李哥/姐, 王大哥/姐, or even just 老大.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition:

Some honorifics are ancient, that means many years ago students used them to call each other, but in recent years they may sounds obsolete.

In the recent 20 years, 同学 is polite enough. It is safe and unisex.

师兄/师姐/师弟/师妹 is closer than 学长/学姐/学弟/学妹 because 师兄 means you and the other are not only alumna, but also have the same teacher.

Titles that come with a specific job is also ok, 主席/会长/部长/组长. But sometimes they may sound a bit bureaucratic on unnecessary occasions.

You can just use 同学 or 学长, or add name before title if you like. Last name is more official, part of first name is more intimate. You can call 李子文: 李同学，子文同学，小文同学.